# Angular 2 reddit clone routing

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm working on a reddit clone as my first Angular 2 application, the code is here:

https://github.com/claysmith/hackerspulse (Using VS Code with .NET Core)

I'm trying to setup the routes like on reddit where if you go to /r/sub it will load articles for a different subreddit.

Here is my router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/r/home', pathMatch:'full' },
{ path: 'r/:id', component : SubverseComponent }];
```

I want when loaded for them to go to the home-sub, and when given route /r/something it will load my subverse component, where I will load articles from the db on ng init based on which subverse it is.

https://github.com/claysmith/hackerspulse/tree/master/wwwroot/app/subverse

However, when I start up the site, routes don't seem to have any effect.

I have it hooked in to my main [app.module.ts](https://github.com/claysmith/hackerspulse/blob/master/wwwroot/app/app.module.ts)

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  ArticleComponent,
  SubverseComponent // <-- added this
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]})
```

But when I try to goto a subreddit I get javascript errors like:

GET http://localhost:5000/r/systemjs.config.js failure (It's looking in /r/ for javascript when it's just in the main path, system.config.js)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHnXH.png

Note it shouldn't be looking in /r/ directory at all for javascript/css, it should be looking in the home directory above it.

Also I'm not redirected to /r/home when loading localhost. And when going to /r/test it doesn't load the subverse component HTML and give a javascript log of the subverse name.

I'm probably making a beginner mistake. Please help.

Edit: I've integrated my app more with MVC, in the startup.cs I put

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            // when the user types in a link handled by client side routing to the address bar 
            // or refreshes the page, that triggers the server routing. The server should pass 
            // that onto the client, so Angular can handle the route
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                template: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
        });
```

Now the javascript files in the /r/ directory are filled with html code of the page. Help?

Edit: Making progress, now it's trying to load subverse component but can't
https://i.stack.imgur.com/11BYS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in my app.component.ts I had to set template to router-outlet like

```
template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
```

And it works! :~)